# Port 80 alternative on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I already have a program running on port 80. Another program that I want to use, also runs on port 80. Is there another alternative port that can be used so that they can be run at the same time?

Comment: What programs? I commonly see this with skype and apache. If that's what your situation is, start apache first, then skype.

Answer (score 1):

you can run a netstat command from a command line - try something like

netstat -an |find  /i "listening"

Answer (score 1):

Port 8080 is an [official](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) alternative port to port 80. So if it is not already in use, it would be a good one to use.

```
http-alt    8080/tcp    HTTP Alternate (see port 80)
http-alt    8080/udp    HTTP Alternate (see port 80)
```

To see what ports are currently in use, I would use the `netstat -a` command to look for connections in the `LISTENING` state

Answer (score 0):

If the app (and the client/server it connects to) allows you to change the port you are good, else you might need to try some kind of port forwarding.

Comment: Great, because they both do actually. But now, how do I find out what other ports are available and which ones I can use?

Comment: If you randomly choose a port, you will most likely get an open. Did you try port 8080? thats another default for http traffic, which should like what you are doing